# Looping through an array of edittexts and getting the texts of each

Tags: java, android

I have an autogenerated list of edittexts gotten from the user input. What i want to do is shuffle the edittexts when the shuffle button is clicked or get the texts and set them to different edittexts. What i tried doing is to get the texts of each edittext adding it to an arraylist and shuffling it and then recreating the layout with the shuffled list. But that in itself is giving me errors. When the shuffle button is clicked it gives me this error
                                                                              java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
Thanks For the help
`

```
   @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnForCreate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCreateTxt);
    editTextForInputToCreate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textForInputToCreate);
    listLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.listLayout);
    btnDisplay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDisplay);
    btnShuffleTxt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnShuffleTxt);


    editTextForInputToCreate.animate().translationX(-1000f);



    btnForCreate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            bringTextInputBackOnScreen();


        }
    });


    btnDisplay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


            if (editTextForInputToCreate.getText().toString().length() >= 0) {
                try {
                    listLayout.removeAllViews();

                } catch (Throwable throwable) {
                    throwable.printStackTrace();
                }
            }


            length = Integer.parseInt(editTextForInputToCreate.getText().toString());


            for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                editTextCollection = new EditText[length];
                editText = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
                editText.setId(i + 1);
                editText.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                editText.setHint("Input" + " " + (i + 1));
                listLayout.addView(editText);
                editTextCollection[i] = editText;


            }


        }


    });


    btnShuffleTxt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            listLayout.removeAllViews();
            for (EditText gottenEditText:editTextCollection)
            {
                String gottenTexts = gottenEditText.getText().toString();
                list.add(gottenTexts);
            }

            Collections.shuffle(list);


        }


    });


}


private void bringTextInputBackOnScreen()
{
    editTextForInputToCreate.animate().translationXBy(1000f).setDuration(2000);
}
```

`

Comment: What kind of errors? Add that information to the question please. And: spend some time to properly format, your source code instead of dropping this mess on other people.

Comment: Will do sorry about that

Comment: Then you want to Google "what is a nullpointerexception" :-)

Answer (score 0):

Please make some corrections in your EditTextCollection.

```
        editTextCollection = new EditText[length];// initialization outside the loop

for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            editText = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
            editText.setId(i + 1);
            editText.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            editText.setHint("Input" + " " + (i + 1));
            listLayout.addView(editText);
            editTextCollection[i] = editText;
        }


btnShuffleTxt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        listLayout.removeAllViews();
        for (EditText gottenEditText:editTextCollection)
        {
            String gottenTexts = gottenEditText.getText().toString();
            list.add(gottenTexts);
        }

    Collections.shuffle(list);

    for (EditText gottenEditText:editTextCollection)
    {
        gottenEditText.setText(list.get(editTextCollection.indexOf(gottenEditText)));
    }

}
```

});

Comment: Yes, i have done that but what i really want to do is to shuffle the edittexts that are displayed in the layout when the shuffle button is clicked. I tried getting the texts and saving it in an array then filling an array list with the texts. Shuffle the arraylist then display the edittexts again with the shuffled values this time.

Comment: I have solved the problem. Thank you everyone who tried to answer